# jQuery multiple deferreds resolved and handled before return

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, asynchronous

I have seen many questions answered regarding multiple deferreds being awaited at once, but I am having difficulty awaiting, and then handling those deferreds before triggering a final "done" event. Consider the following code, where I have a list of deferreds that is awaited, and then for each deferred I want to handle the resolved value so that I can return the result of each deferred as a backbone collection once they are all done.

The problem I am having is that the event is being fired before all of the deferred.done() lambdas are completing. Are there ways that I could make this synchronous?

(I am using Backbone models/collections and Underscore)

```
var deferreds = [];
_.forEach(upcs, function(upc){
    deferreds.push(getProduct(upc));  //getProduct() returns a deferred
});

$.when.apply($, deferreds).done(function(){
    var products = new Products();

    _.forEach(deferreds, function(deferred){
        deferred.done(function(product) {  //deferred resolve() returns product
            products.add(product);
        });
    });

    that.trigger("claimed", products);  //fire fully resolved collection
});
```

Comment: it occurs to me that this may be achievable by use of a second list of deferreds resolved inside of each done() lambda, but that seems clumsy to me

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/m1uLnczv/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The results of all the promises are available as the [`$.when` promise's](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/) *result*. They're given as the [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments) to your handler:

```
$.when.apply($, deferreds).done(function() {
    var products = new Products();
    _.forEach(arguments, function(product) {
        products.add(product);
    });
    that.trigger("claimed", products);  //fire fully resolved collection
});
```

Comment: I don't think you will get an array as the argument... you will get as many params as the passed deferred items.. see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/m1uLnczv/3/

Comment: @ArunPJohny: You're correct. I always forget how messy jQuery's `when` is.

Comment: I see, the results being passed back were invisible to me, thanks for the help!